# Editar elementos da tabela

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Existe algum meio de editar os elementos da tabela criada com uma função `JavaScript` diretamente na tabela, com um click duplo?

Eu criei uma função que usa três inputs para imprimir na tabela seus respectivos valores, como sou novato na área ainda não conheço muito sobre a linguagem.

Talvez seja mais fácil um meio que manda os valores da `tr` para os inputs
com um dblevent.

```js
function adicionarItem() {
  var refNome = document.querySelector("#nome").value;
  var refCpf = document.querySelector("#cpf").value;
  var refRg = document.querySelector("#rg").value;

  var usuarioTr = document.createElement("tr");
  usuarioTr.className = "user";

  var selec = document.createElement('td');
  selec.className = 'usr';
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  input.className = 'check';
  selec.appendChild(input);
  var nomeTd = document.createElement("td");
  var cpfTd = document.createElement("td");
  var rgTd = document.createElement("td");

  nomeTd.textContent = refNome;
  cpfTd.textContent = refCpf;
  rgTd.textContent = refRg;

  usuarioTr.appendChild(selec);
  usuarioTr.appendChild(nomeTd);
  usuarioTr.appendChild(cpfTd);
  usuarioTr.appendChild(rgTd);

  var tabela = document.querySelector("#tabela");

  tabela.appendChild(usuarioTr);
}

function removerItem() {
  ckList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  ckList.forEach(function(el, index) {
    if (ckList[index].checked) el.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Teste01</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<script src="./main.js"></script>

<section>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
      <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome aqui" autofocus/>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
      <input id="cpf" name="cpf" type="number" placeholder="Digite seu CPF" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="rg">RG:</label>
      <input id="rg" name="rg" type="number" placeholder="Digite seu RG" />
    </div>

    <button id="adicionarBotao" onclick="adicionarItem()" type="button">Adicionar</button>
    <button id="editarBotao" onclick="" type="button">Editar</button>
    <button id="excluirBotao" onclick="removerItem()" type="button">Excluir</button>
  </form>
</section>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Selecionar</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>CPF</th>
      <th>RG</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabela">
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando apenas javascript, é possível fazer e edição na célula sim, segue um exemplo:

```js
function saveNew() {
  var $tr = document.createElement('tr');
  
  $tr.appendChild(createCell('nome'));
  $tr.appendChild(createCell('cpf'));
  $tr.appendChild(createCell('rg'));
  
  $btExcluir = document.createElement('button');
  $btExcluir.innerHTML = 'Excluir';
  $btExcluir.addEventListener('click', remove);

  $tdActions = document.createElement('td');
  $tdActions.appendChild($btExcluir);

  $tr.appendChild($tdActions);
  
  document.getElementById('data').appendChild($tr);
}

function createCell(name) {
  var $td = document.createElement('td');
  $td.innerHTML = document.querySelector('[name="' + name + '"]').value;

  $td.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var $td = this;
    $input = document.createElement('input');
    $input.type = 'text';
    $input.value = this.innerHTML;
    $input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
      $td.innerHTML = this.value;
    });
    
    this.innerHTML = '';
    this.appendChild($input);
  });

  return $td;
}

function remove() {
  var $tr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  $tr.parentNode.removeChild($tr);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>CPF</th>
      <th>RG</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data"></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="nome"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cpf"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rg"></td>
      <td><button onclick="saveNew()">Salvar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não acredito que jQuery seja a melhor saída para esse tipo de coisa. Me parece que você está tentando dar uma certa "reatividade" a sua aplicação e, nesse caso te aconselho partir para o [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

[Nesse link](https://jsfiddle.net/yobyzal/gehtwxeo/) você pode encontrar um exemplo simples do que você está procurando.